# When i click on faq or about us the screen still on settings fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

so i'm trying to make an app for a university project, and i got something is not working well in my code, so i make a menu sidebar and with some separatores like profile, events, about us, FAQ, settings, share and logout

**SideBar**

[image: **SideBar**]

So i create some fragments

**Fragments**

[image: **Fragments**]

But now i'm having problem with the fragments about us and FAQ when i click on the about us or FAQ it goes to settings fragment and i don't know why?
could someone help me?

**MainActivity.Java**

```
package com.example.readytogo;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView =findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new ProfileFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_profile);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_events:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new EventsFragment()).commit();
            case R.id.nav_aboutus:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AboutUsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_faq:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FAQFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
        }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**drawer_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="Navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_events"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
            android:title="Events" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_aboutus"
            android:icon="@mipmap/aboutus"
            android:title="About us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_faq"
            android:icon="@mipmap/faq"
            android:title="FAQ" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
                android:title="Share" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="Sign in">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@mipmap/arrow"
                android:title="Log out" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: How are you adding the `MenuItems`?

Comment: On app>res>menu>drawer_menu.xml

Comment: Something like this  <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
            android:title="Profile" />

Comment: check if all the items have separate IDs that you have specified in your java code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any case of About & FAQ inside `onNavigationItemSelected()` .
Also, please make sure you have set correct id for About Us & FAQ inside `nav_view.xml` (not `nav_settings`) that could be one possible reason it's opening `SettingsFragment`.

Comment: Hello, hmm i update the code please check if is now ok? but i didn't understand what u are saying about nav_view.xml, sorry i'm a really beginner on this, sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Oops! I meant drawer_menu.xml.

Comment: Got it! break is missing between nav_events & about_us. Please correct it 
& check

Answer (score 2):

You are missing on click event for FAQ and About us Page. You need to add..

```
case R.id.nav_faq: // the id will be the one you are using in your xml
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new FAQFragment()).commit();
                break;

case R.id.nav_about_us: // the id will be the one you are using in your xml
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new AboutUsFragment()).commit();
                break;
```

Add them where you have added other events.

Comment: ok u are right! but after i do dat the events fragment goes to about us everything else works only this fragment events is not working

Comment: "events fragment goes to about us everything" because break is missing between the two.

Answer (score 1):

```
make sure you have set correct id for About Us & FAQ inside app>res>menu>
and add these two lines in onNavigationItemSelected Method.I have mentioned below just check and put your id in that switch case

    @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){  

  case R.id.nav_profile:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new ProfileFragment()).commit();
    break;
    case R.id.nav_events:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new EventsFragment()).commit();
    break;
    case R.id.about_us:
    Toast.makeText(this, "About us", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.faq:
    Toast.makeText(this, "FAQ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.nav_settings:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    break;
    case R.id.nav_share:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    case R.id.nav_logout:
    Toast.makeText(this, "Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
```